# async CollectionViewSource filtering with progress reporting?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

async CollectionViewSource filtering with progress reporting?

I'm modifying a search on a `CollectionViewSource` from sync to async as the typical size of the collection has increased massively. The reason is to give the user progress reporting. The problem is I don't see a way to reference the `Progress<int>` object within the filtering event handler. The example below has a working async method with progresss reporting and the skeleton of the `Filter` approach showing my quandary. I don't know a way to implement a `ProgressBar` for a `Filter` operation on a `CollectionViewSource`.

```
<Window x:Class="testProgressFilter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testProgressFilter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VM x:Key="VM" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource VM}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="30">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <ProgressBar Minimum="{Binding ProgressBarMinimum}" Maximum="{Binding ProgressBarMaximum}" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}"
                             Height="30" Width="300"/>
                <Button Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="30" Width="75" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Content="Cancel"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Margin="0,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="125" Command="{Binding FilterCommand}" 
                    Content="Do a filter" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonsAreEnabled}"/>
            <Button Margin="0,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="125" Command="{Binding AltCommand}" 
                    Content="Do something else" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonsAreEnabled}"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The View Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using custAssembliesx64;

namespace testProgressFilter
{
    internal class VM : Notifier
    {
        private int progressBarMinimum = 0;
        public int ProgressBarMinimum
        {
            get { return progressBarMinimum; }
            set
            {
                if (progressBarMinimum != value)
                {
                    progressBarMinimum = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ProgressBarMinimum");
                }
            }
        }

        private int progressBarMaximum = 100;
        public int ProgressBarMaximum
        {
            get { return progressBarMaximum; }
            set
            {
                if (progressBarMaximum != value)
                {
                    progressBarMaximum = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ProgressBarMaximum");
                }
            }
        }

        private int progressBarValue;
        public int ProgressBarValue
        {
            get { return progressBarValue; }
            set
            {
                if (progressBarValue != value)
                {
                    progressBarValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ProgressBarValue");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool buttonsAreEnabled = true;
        public bool ButtonsAreEnabled
        {
            get { return buttonsAreEnabled; }
            set
            {
                if (buttonsAreEnabled != value)
                {
                    buttonsAreEnabled = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ButtonsAreEnabled");
                }
            }
        }

        internal static bool IsCancelled = false;
        ObservableCollection<int> ints = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        CollectionViewSource CollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        const int maxvals = 2000;
        const int halfMaxvals = maxvals / 2;

        int ItemsCount;
        int ItemsCountPercent;
        int prevItemsCountPercent;
        const float cent = (float)100 / (float)maxvals;

        public VM()
        {
            CollectionViewSource.Source = ints;
            // populate the collection
            for (int i = 0; i < maxvals; i++)
            {
                ints.Add(i);
            }
        }

        public ICommand FilterCommand => new RelayCommand(DoFilter);
        private async void DoFilter(object parm)
        {
            // filter the collection, showing progress
            ButtonsAreEnabled = false;
            int totalItems = maxvals;
            var progress = new Progress<int>(percent => { ProgressBarValue = percent; });
            await Task.Run(() => DoFilterTask(totalItems, progress));
            IsCancelled = false;
            ButtonsAreEnabled = true;
            CollectionViewSource.Filter -= FilterCriteria;
         }

        private void DoFilterTask(int totalItems, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                CollectionViewSource.Filter += FilterCriteria;
            }); 
         }

        private void FilterCriteria(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsCancelled) return;
            int j = (int)e.Item;

            // REPORT PROGRESS HERE!

            if (j < halfMaxvals)
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
        }

        public ICommand AltCommand => new RelayCommand(DoAlt);

        private async void DoAlt(object parm)
        {
            ButtonsAreEnabled = false;
            int totalItems = maxvals;
            ProgressBarMinimum = 0;
            ProgressBarMaximum = 100;
            ProgressBarValue = 0;
            var progress = new Progress<int>(percent => { ProgressBarValue = percent; });
            await Task.Run(() => DoAltTask(totalItems, progress));
            IsCancelled = false;
            ButtonsAreEnabled = true;
        }

        private void DoAltTask(int totalItems, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            //  doing something else with the collection, showing progress
            ItemsCount = 0;
            ItemsCountPercent = 0;
            prevItemsCountPercent = 0;

            double x = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++)
            {
                if (IsCancelled) break;
                x += i / 1048576;
                Thread.Sleep(1);

                ItemsCount++;
                // report progress when > 1 additional percent is surpassed
                ItemsCountPercent = (int)(cent * (float)ItemsCount);
                if (ItemsCountPercent > prevItemsCountPercent)
                {
                    prevItemsCountPercent = ItemsCountPercent;
                    if (progress != null)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            progress.Report(ItemsCountPercent);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
        public ICommand CancelCommand => new RelayCommand(DoCancel);
        private void DoCancel(object parm)
        {
            IsCancelled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using a special package for MVVM?

Comment: could you post your complete project to github or  another place , it will be easier to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Why do you need `Progress<int>` at all? Why not `Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ProgressBarValue = <some value>;})`?

Comment: @Frenchy It's vanilla WPF/C#. `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand` use my code in separate assembies.

Comment: @Rekshino `IProgress.Report()` is needed for progressive reporting. The UI remains blocked otherwise.

Comment: Your `Task.Run` is just turning around and doing a `Dispatcher.Invoke`, so that's not going to do anything useful.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought `Progress<int>` is just needed to couple/decouple progress reporting in business layer to the (captured)synchronization context if there is, but it has nothing to do with "blocked UI". You have to do heavy load on a some non GUI thread, but report on GUI via `Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ProgressBarValue = <some value>;})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is really good,

another solution using only the dispatcher:

1. create Loaded Event in progress Bar definion XAML (called ProgressBarLoaded)

use it in viem model

```
    public void ProgressBarLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bar = sender as ProgressBar;
        ItemsCount = 0;
        ItemsCountPercent = 0;
    }
```

and in FilterCriteria update the value :

```
    private void FilterCriteria(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsCancelled) return;
        int j = (int)e.Item;

        if (j < halfMaxvals)
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }

        ItemsCountPercent = ++ItemsCount * 100 / maxvals;
        bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => bar.Value = ItemsCountPercent, DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
```

No need to define binding to ProgressBarValue..

In this sample, i play with progress bar during the filtering of the collection

Comment: Thank you, Frenchy. Your solution works in my example as you said, and the application's logic is similar so I'm confident it will work there too and my problem is solved.

Comment: happy to help you, dont forget to close your question by validating the answer you prefer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, creating a background thread which does nothing but posting its complete work back to the UI thread (see your `DoFilterTask` method) is pretty useless and waste of resources. It creates an unnecessary overhead.

Same applies to this code smell:

```cs
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
  progress.Report(ItemsCountPercent);
});
```

The whole point of using `IProgress<T>` is to post the progress delegate execution back to the original dispatcher thread. So why additionally call `Dispatcher:Invoke`? `Dispatcher.Invoke` is redundant. At this point I don't want to mention the rest of your code that doesn't make much sense. Just had to highlight the wrong use of `IProgress<T>` and the `Dispatcher` (especially in context of a background thread).

Second, you only experience bad filtering performance if you display the data items in a view that does not has UI virtualization enabled or doesn't support it (like the plain `ItemsControl`) or you are loading way too many items.

In case we have that many items, we usually get them from a database or some kind of data service in general. In such case you must not filter the source collection of your view but query the data source for a filtered result. For example, offloading the work to a server or database will significantly improve the performance.
Using an `ItemsControl` that supports UI virtualization (for example `ListBox`) is mandatory if you want to reduce the choppy feel of your UI when applying big changes (like filtering) to your source collection.

I also hope that the `Thread.Sleep` is not in your production code. Because why would you artificially slow down your algorithm (and then show a progress bar)?

However, because of the `Dispatcher` affinity of the `CollectionView` (if used as a `Binding.Source`) you can't manipulate it on another thread than the dispatcher thread that is associated with the `CollectionView`.
For this reason, you must create a temporary `CollectionView` that is disconnected from the UI thread in order to manipulate it from a background thread.
In your case it would be easier to create a temporary collection which you later assign to the `ItemsSource` property of e.g. a `ListBox` (or any other `ItemsControl` that supports UI virtualization).

The following example keeps the UI responsive while filtering a big source collection in the view:
**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" 
             Maximum="{Binding NumericItems.Count}" 
             Height="8" />
<Button Content="Filter Items"
        Click="Button_Click" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NumericItems}" 
         Height="500" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<int> NumericItems
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(NumericItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(NumericItemsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty NumericItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "NumericItems", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.NumericItems = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var rndGenerator = new Random();
    int itemCount = 10000
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
      int number = rndGenerator.Next(0, itemCount);
      this.NumericItems.Add(number);
    }
  }

  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var tempList = this.NumericItems.ToList();
    IProgress<int> progressReporter = new Progress<int>(progressValue => this.ProgressBar.Value = progressValue);
    int processedItemCount = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      for (int index = tempList.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
      {
        int value = tempList[index];
        if (!IsItemIncluded(value))
        {
          tempList.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        progressReporter.Report(++processedItemCount);
      }
    });

    // If the data view is not using UI virtualization, 
    // this operation will cause the UI to hang until the data view is initialized.
    this.NumericItems = new ObservableCollection<int>(tempList);
  }

  private bool IsItemIncluded(int item) => item % 2 == 0;
}
```